# Can't access $_SESSION data through AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

So I will try to explain my problem. I have searched for answer but nothing.
So in my web app I load items like objects then serialize them and store in $_SESSION[index] = $serializedObj. 
Then I send Ajax request to server:

```
.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/renderItem.php",
        data: { id: 5}
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $(".item-wrap").append(data);
    });
```

At the `renderItem.php` I get this id and make variable

```
$unserializedObj = unserialize($_SESSION[$_POST['id']]);
$unserializedObj->outputItem();
```

Then i get data and append to needed `div`, but php says that its undefinied variable `_SESSION`. How can I access to these variables, should I define them in different way or I need to use cookies if I want to get this work?

Comment: Where do you call `session_start()`?

Comment: you have to set dataType:json in ajax request

Comment: `session_start()` is called at the start when I load items from database. And I have tried call it like string to `unserialize($_SESSION['5'])`

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` in renderItem.php once & check if there is anything in the session? It might be that your session is not accessible in this file.

Comment: When I make `dataType: json` then nothing happens. Not even a error appers. Maybe I do it wrong, can someone please show me some example?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` shows null, but Im sure that the session data is accessible in that file.

Comment: I tried store the object in `$GLOBALS` , like constants too `define()` but nothing. I nood to access to variables when post with ajax, but how??

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to start your session:

```
session_start();
$unserializedObj = unserialize($_SESSION[$_POST['id']]);
$unserializedObj->outputItem();
```

Comment: If I start session in renderItem.php then It returns that its a undefinied offset. Basically that session data dont exists.